# What is np.uint8?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is `np.unit9` possible? Why it is use?

```
red_lower = np.array([136, 87, 111], np.uint9)
```

Comment: The numpy types are described here: https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/user/basics.types.html It is an **u**nsigned **int**eger of **8** bits. That makes the numbers 0 - 254 possible. It's not clear what part you don't understand. Maybe you could clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#unsigned-integer-types

```
class numpy.ubyte[source]
Unsigned integer type, compatible with C unsigned char.

Character code
'B'

Alias on this platform (Linux x86_64)
numpy.uint8: 8-bit unsigned integer (0 to 255).
```

Most often this is used for arrays representing images, with the 3 color channels having small integer values (0 to 255).